# How to unwind through progrmmatically set rootVC (tabViewController) from child tab to different VC that was not instantiated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Swift 5 / xCode 11.5

When the app begins, App Delegate will check for a saved auth token on the users phone. If it is not present it will display what is the **InitialViewController** (instantiating it, setting it as rootViewController, and displaying it in the Window). If token is present it will instantiate and set the **MainTabController** as the rootVC and display it. The hierarchy looks like this:

**RegisterViewController** <-> (No nav controllers between) **InitialViewController**  <->
**LoginViewController** 
 All above controllers push to **MainTabController** if successful login or registration, assuming auth token for user is not present on phone (no nav controllers between any of these 'views', just pushing/dismissing.).
**MainTabController** has three tabs that are UIViewControllers connected through NavControllers.

Since the rootVC is instantiated and displayed through Window object programmatically in the AppDelegate, the **InitialViewController** is not available to unwind to from a tab on the **MainTabController** (which was set as the rootVC), assuming the user does have a saved auth token.

My work around was deleting the auth token then calling a function in AppDelegate that would switch the rootViewController and have the Window display it (back to **InitialViewController**). I worry about all the other VC's that were instantiated though and the memory pile up this may cause. Are all the **MainTabController's** children de-allocated when I do this? Here is code for logout action and switching rootVC:

*logout*

```
@IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
        
        UserServices.logoutUser() {
            responseResult in
            if responseResult == .Success {
                CommonUtils.clearAuthToken()
                CommonUtils.clearAllUserDefaultData()
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.switchRootViewController()
            } else {
                self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: responseResult.rawValue)
            }
        }
}
```

*switchRootViewController in AppDelegate*

```
func switchRootViewController() -> Void {
        let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
    }
```

*What I've tried with the unwind segue already (inside logout action)*

```
        let initialController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
        initialController.addChild(self) // self is tab VC I'm trying to unwind from
        let children = initialController.children

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToHomeScreen", sender: self)
```

*The InitialViewControllers unwind segue code*

```
    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func canPerformUnwindSegueAction(_ action: Selector, from fromViewController: UIViewController, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToInitialViewController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

I don't think this unwind is working because no reference exists for the **InitialViewController**. I'd display a picture of the layout but the project is secret in nature until product launch... Please let me know if you need more info or I was not clear in my description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
func ToSomeScreen() {
    
    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Storyboard ID") as? ScreenCustummerViewController  //file name for next screen
    
    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Comment: My current implementation for switching the rootVC works, I was just asking if I would be creating a memory leak because all the children of the MainTabController are not being destroyed. The docs also say with `makeKeyAndVisible()` the window will:
> position it in front of all other windows at the same level or lower
and I need them all dismissed or de-allocated. Or find some way to unwind through the MainTabController.